# Is there a more object oriented method for selecting a class based on a string than using if-else statements (or switch)?

Tags: java, oop

I have a system where I receive a string from an outside library, and need to select a specific class based on that string. Unfortunately, I have no control over the string I receive. Is there a more object-oriented way to do this in Java than

```
if(string.equals(CASE1)){
  return new CaseOneObject();
} else if (string.equals(CASE2)){
  return new CaseTwoObject();
} else if
...
```

Each string corresponds to a single class, but there isn't a reliable way to derive the class name from the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or put the names or classes in a map and select them using the string as the key.

```
Map<String, Class<?>> classes = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>;
Class<?> aClass = com.github.my.overlong.package.SomeClass.class;
classes.put("silly_string_a", aClass);
/* .... */
```

Answer (score 2):

You could setup a static mapping like this at the top of your class managing this:

```
static Map<String, Class<?>> classMap = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
static {
    classMap.put("case1", CaseOneObject.class);
    classMap.put("case2", CaseTwoObject.class);
}
```

And then lookup the string you get from the outside library to create an instance if it's available:

```
Class<?> clazz = classMap.get(string);
if (clazz != null) {
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the String to classname mapping in a map. Use reflection with proper exception handling to instantiate the class

*Edit*

```
map.put ("case1", "class1")
....

Class.forName(map.get("case1")).newInstance();
```

However, you will need to Type the returned object to desired one before being able to do something useful with it.

Comment: Could you go into that a little more please?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to store a map of your instances and use it when the string has sent

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("SomeString",new MyObject());
map.put("SomeString2",new MyObject2());
```

or you can save the class instead of new MyObject2() and create new instance.

now when you want to get the data you go:

```
return map.get(myString);
```

Comment: unless they are all implementing some interface, it will be hard to determine which class the returned object should be casted to.

Comment: I also wrote: `or you can save the class instead of new MyObject2() and create new instance`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, there is the `Map<String, Object>` solution, which is quite nice; however if you really want to switch off of Strings, you cannot do it until Java 7 becomes available.

Project coin added several extensions to the Java language.  One of those extensions was "switch statements based on Strings", an example of the supported String enabled switch statement follows.

SIMPLE EXAMPLE: Show the simplest possible program utilizing the new feature.

```
String s = ...
switch(s) {
 case "foo":
   processFoo(s);
   break;
}
```

ADVANCED EXAMPLE: Show advanced usage(s) of the feature.

```
String s = ...
switch(s) {
case "quux":
   processQuux(s);
   // fall-through

 case "foo":
 case "bar":
   processFooOrBar(s);
   break;

 case "baz":
    processBaz(s);
   // fall-through

 default:
   processDefault(s);
   break;
}
```

Comment: This will be convenient when it comes out, but I don't think the switch is actually any more object-oriented than the corresponding if-else.

Comment: I too tend to regard switch as non-object oriented; but, they are likely to be around just as long as those corresponding if-else statements you mentioned.  An odd thing to consider is that if groups of if-else statements are inherently not very object-oriented, then are standalone if statements very object-oriented?

Comment: Oh, I don't really mind them at all, I'd just rather there was a quicker way to expand my list than actually having to go to it and expand it. If I'm writing a new class, and there was a way to do it with various classes, then that would be preferable. Using a map, as has been suggested elsewhere, is really the same thing as the if-else/switch alternative, it just moves that determination logic somewhere else (and adds overhead as well). So, it looks like what I've got is really the least awkward solution available.